# QoS in Spring Cloud Stream apps

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to ensure apps are configured to a specific quality-of-service in spring cloud stream. I am assuming at-least-once is the default configuration but is there a way to ensure that application or the rabbitmq platform is going to use one, when using SCSt.

1. At most once
2. At least once
3. Exactly once

I am unable to configure QoS parameter for the SCSt apps.